# .SQLiteException: near “00”: syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, calendar

I am new to android, and I tried to compare two date strings, but I always get this, I don't know how to solve.. Here is the part of code where I have mistake

```
int year=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)+1900;

int month=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

int day=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DbReminders bazaDelete=new DbReminders(context);

bazaDelete.open();

bazaDelete.deleteReminder("DATE<"+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" 00:00 AM");

bazaDelete.close();

podsetniciAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Post the complete logcat. Also please post more relevant code

Comment: Your date field is a string. So this won't be accepted: `"DATE<"+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" 00:00 AM"`. Try this instead. `"DATE < '" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " 00:00 AM'"` (notice the use of the string delimiters, **'**)

Comment: It works, but now I have another problem because it deletes all items from database, not only with older date, but that's another problem, thanks for this.